# Initializing Location stream after re-login flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter app, I am sending users location as long as they are logged in. The first time that the user logs in the process starts successfully, but after sign out and log into app again the `LocationService().locationStream;` is not initialized correctly and the stream is not being send. I do not now how to call/ initialize the  `LocationService().locationStream;` correctly from login screen. LocationService is singleton.

These are the related calsses:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  static LocationService? locationService = LocationService();

  const MyApp({
    Key? key,
    required this.homepage,
    required this.isLoggedIn,
    required this.isLightTheme,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final bool? isLoggedIn;
  final String homepage;
  final bool isLightTheme;

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  //LocationService? locationService;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    PedometerService.instance.init();
    //locationService = LocationService();
    startLocation();
  }
  Future<void> startLocation() async {
    await MyApp.locationService?.getLocationOnchange(context);
    MyApp.locationService?.getListener();
    startLocationStream();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.isLoggedIn ?? false) {
      MyApp.locationService ??= LocationService();
      startLocation();
    }
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Semdatex Patient Portal',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: widget.isLightTheme ? lightMode : darkMode,
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      locale: context.locale,
      initialRoute: widget.homepage,
      home: PushMessaging(
        isLoggedIn: widget.isLoggedIn,
        homepage: widget.homepage,
        title: "Semdatex Patient Portal",
      ),
      routes: {
        '/questionnairePushNotificationRoot': (context) => const QuestionnaireRoot(),
        '/singleChoiceNew': (context) => const SelectionWindow(),
        '/exercisePrescriptionPage': (context) => const ExercisePrescriptionHome(),

      },
    );
  }
}
```

Main class:

```
    Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
}

late AndroidNotificationChannel channel;
late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();

  final messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  final routeFromMessageCompleter = Completer<String>();

  // Request permission for receiving notifications
  await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );

  // Get the initial message if available
  messaging.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
    if (message != null) {
      routeFromMessageCompleter.complete("/${message.data['route']}");
    } else {
      routeFromMessageCompleter.complete("");
    }
  });

  // Background message handling
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);

  // Initialize FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
  if (!kIsWeb) {
    channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'high_importance_channel',
      'High Importance Notifications',
      importance: Importance.high,
    );
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
  }

  // Get FCM token and save it
  final fcmToken = await messaging.getToken();
  SharedPref.saveFCMToken(fcmToken);

  // Check if the user is logged in
  final bool isLoggedIn = await SharedPref.getUserLoginSharedPrefernces() ?? false;
  final String routeFromMessage = await routeFromMessageCompleter.future;
  String route = isLoggedIn && routeFromMessage != '' ? routeFromMessage : (isLoggedIn ? '/' : '/loginScreen');
  runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        return EasyLocalization(
          supportedLocales: const [
            Locale('en', 'US'),
            Locale('es', 'ES'),
            Locale('nl', 'NL'),
            Locale('de', 'DE'),
          ],
          path: 'i18n',
          fallbackLocale: const Locale('en', 'US'),
          child: MyApp(
            homepage: route,
            isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
            isLightTheme: true,
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
  );
}
```

LoginScreen:

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<LoginScreen> {
  bool isLoading = false;
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  User user = User("", "", "");

  String url = urlBase + "v1/mob/login";
  String urlLanguage = urlBase + "v1/mob/language";

  Future save() async {
    String? token = await SharedPref.getFCMToken();
    var res = await post(url, {
      'email': user.email.toLowerCase().trim(),
      'password': user.password,
      'firebaseToken': token,
    }).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 3));
    if (res.body.isEmpty) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('loginUnsuccessfull'.tr());
      }
      _showMyDialog();
    } else {
      var data = json.decode(res.body);
      if (data["patientNumber"] == null) {
        _showMyDialog();
      } else {
        await savePatientNumber(data["patientNumber"], data["lastAccess"]);
        await SharedPref.saveLoginSharedPreference(true);
        try {
          sendMetadata();
        } catch (e) {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print(e);
          }
        }
        try{

          var language = data["language"];
          if (language != null){
            String languageCode = '';
            String countryCode = '';
            switch (language){
              case "en":
                languageCode = "en";
                countryCode = "US";
                break;
              case "es":
                languageCode = "es";
                countryCode = "ES";
                break;
              case "nl":
                languageCode = "nl";
                countryCode = "NL";
                break;
              case "de":
                languageCode = "de";
                countryCode = "DE";
                break;
            }
            await EasyLocalization.of(context)?.setLocale(Locale(languageCode, countryCode));
          }
        }catch (e){
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print(e);
          }
        }
       // final locationService = LocationService();
        MyApp.locationService ??= LocationService();
        MyApp.locationService?.initListenerIfNeeded();
        MyApp.locationService?.getListener();
        startLocationStream();
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
      }
    }
  }....
```

LocationService:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart' as perm;

import '../../Datamodel/user_location.dart';

class LocationService {
  static final LocationService _instance = LocationService._internal();
  bool _isStreamInitialized = false;

  factory LocationService() {
    return _instance;
  }

  LocationService._internal({BuildContext? context}) {
    if (context != null) {
      getLocationOnchange(context);
    }
  }

  Location location = Location();
  final StreamController<UserLocation> _locationController =
  StreamController<UserLocation>.broadcast();
  StreamSubscription<LocationData>? listener;

  Stream<UserLocation> get locationStream => _locationController.stream;

  Future<void> getLocationOnchange(BuildContext context) async {
    await showPermissionDialogAndAskPermission(context, perm.Permission.location);
    listener ??= initListener();
  }

  Future<void> showPermissionDialogAndAskPermission(
      BuildContext context, perm.Permission permission) async {
    final perm.PermissionStatus status = await permission.status;
    if (status.isGranted) {
      location.enableBackgroundMode(enable: true);
      location.changeSettings(
        interval: 10000,
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
      );
      listener = initListener();
    } else if (status.isDenied || status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext dialogContext) {
          return AlertDialog(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.5),
            ),
            title: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                const Text("Permission required"),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pop(dialogContext);
                  },
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.close,
                    size: 6.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            content: const Text(
              "This app collects location data to enable suggesting you to do activities which are beneficiary for your health"
                  "even when the app is closed or not in use."
            ),
            actionsPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 5.0),
            actions: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text("Cancel"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () async {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        final perm.PermissionStatus newStatus = await permission.request();
                        if (newStatus.isGranted) {
                          location.enableBackgroundMode(enable: true);
                          location.changeSettings(
                            interval: 10000,//
                            accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
                          );
                          initListenerIfNeeded();
                          //listener = initListener();
                        } else if (newStatus.isDenied) {
                          // Permission denied
                        } else if (newStatus.isPermanentlyDenied) {
                          // Permission permanently denied
                        }
                      },
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text("Grant"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
            actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          );
        },
      );
    } else {
      // Handle other permission statuses if needed
    }
  }

  StreamSubscription<LocationData>? getListener() {
    return listener;
  }

  void initListenerIfNeeded() {
    if (!_isStreamInitialized) {
      listener = initListener();
      _isStreamInitialized = true;
    }
  }
  StreamSubscription<LocationData> initListener() {
    return location.onLocationChanged.listen((locationData) {
      if (!_locationController.isClosed) {
        _locationController.add(UserLocation(
          locationData.latitude,
          locationData.longitude,
          locationData.altitude,
          locationData.time,
        ));
      }
    });
  }
  void initListeners() {
    listener ??= initListener();
  }
  void dispose() {
    _locationController.close();
    listener?.cancel();
    listener = null;

  }
}
```

postlocation:

```
startLocationStream() async {
  var patient = await getPatient();
  var patNumber = patient[0]["PatNum"];
  MyApp.locationService?.initListenerIfNeeded();
  MyApp.locationService ??= LocationService();
  Stream<UserLocation>? l = LocationService().locationStream;
  String url = urlBase + "v1/mob/location";
  UserLocation locationData;
  l.listen((event) {
    locationData = UserLocation(
        event.latitude, event.longitude, event.altitude, event.time);
    try {
      post(
          url,
          {
            'latitude': locationData.latitude,
            'altitude': locationData.altitude,
            'longitude': locationData.longitude,
            'time': locationData.time,
            'patientNumber': patNumber
          });
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
  });
}
```